# Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4. error when uploading image using AWS S3 V3

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I'm using S3 v3 in the exact way as in AWS's documentation but I always get this message:
[image]

I've checked various posts of how to solve this but always seem to get the same result, I cannot see what's the issue here.

```
const creds = {
    accessKeyId: "****************",
    secretAccessKey: "****************",
};

const S3Client = new S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    region: 'us-east-2',
    credentials: creds,
})
    const [image, setImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

    const addImage = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const file = e.target.files?.[0]!;

        if (!file) {
            return ;
        };

        setImage(file);
    };

    const uploadImage: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!image) {
            return ;
        };

        const input = {
            Bucket:'******',
            Key: image.name,
            Body: image,
        }

        const command = new PutObjectCommand(input);
        const response = await S3Client.send(command);
    }
```

It uploads the image successfully but I get the message in the image above when clicking on it, I also tried using S3Client from @aws-sdk/client-s3 and still the same.